# Format natbib font style

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, natbib

I want to change the font style of the journal in the bibliography from italic to medium using natbib?

`\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}` 
allows to change the size but I haven't find an option for changing the style.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: The font of the journal is controlled by your bibliography style. So we need to know which style you use. Please show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Here's a MWE of what I have:  \usepackage[round]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{referencias}

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Not entirely sure what you have in mind, so a MWE would have helped, but this changes the style to italic.  `biblatex` is worth looking into; it has more features than `natbib`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{hi.bib}
@artice{nut,
author={Nut Job},
year={2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\citet{nut}


\bibliography{hi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but what I need is to turn the whole reference to normal font 

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vm16.png


This is the way it's formated and it's exactly right for what I need but the journal is in italic and I need it to be in normalfont. 

I would use biblatex but it generates square braquets.