# change citation font style using natbib

Tags: fonts, bibtex, citing, natbib

How can I change the font style of the authorname in a citation like `\citep{}` to `\textsc`?

I tried changing the command of `\citep` to `\textsc{\citep}` (see MWE).
But this of course creates problems with multiple authors, as i don't want any "and" printed in \textsc as well.

But there must be a way to refer to the authorname similar to `\bibfont` being the reference to the fontstyle of the bibliography.

I read the natbib documenation and searched this forum. similar problems only focused on the package biblatex.
However, let's assume I don't want to change the package.

Note: this is not the same question as this: 
[Format natbib font style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383447/format-natbib-font-style)
(which is about fontstyles in the bibliography):

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[authoryear,sort]{natbib}            
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@artice{who,
author={Dr Who},
title={said that},
year={2017}
}

@artice{no,
author={Dr No},
title={said otherwise},
year={2017}
}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\textsc{\citeauthor{#1}} (\citeyear{#1})}
\renewcommand{\citep}[1]{(\textsc{\citeauthor{#1}} \citeyear{#1})}
\makeatother

I say this \citep{who,no}.
\cite{who} said that.

\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You would have to edit the formatting routine for author names in the `bst` file used by `natbib`. The package documentation states that you can declare custom `bst` files in a `natbib.cfg` file.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but in my understanding having a *.cfg file is about the same as having a '\makeatletter' section before \begin{document} where I change the setting with '\renewcommand' etc which still leaves me with the problem of how to refer to the authorname cite font

Comment: OK. I was thinking about formatting the names in the bibliography, but it seems that `\bibliographystyle{dinat}` already takes care of that. For the in-text citations, it seems you have to redefine the internal macro `\NAT@nmfmt'. See answer below for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `natbib` package uses the macro `\NAT@nmfmt` to format the author names in in-text citations. We can redefine it to use small caps.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[authoryear,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\def\NAT@nmfmt#1{\textsc{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@artice{who,
author={Dr Who},
title={said that},
year={2017}
}

@artice{no,
author={Dr No},
title={said otherwise},
year={2017}
}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

I say this \citep{who,no}.
\cite{who} said that.

\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

Note that this redefinition will prevent natbib's package option `nonamebreak` from working. The effect of that option should be obtained with

```
\makeatletter
\def\NAT@nmfmt#1{\mbox{\textsc{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

instead of the above redefinition.

Please note that I tested this answer only with your example code and not with any larger real-life document.

Comment: Seems to be working just fine! Thank you so much